# How to remove non-alphanumeric characters?

Tags: php, regex, string

I need to remove all characters from a string which aren't in `a-z A-Z 0-9` set or are not spaces.

Does anyone have a function to do this?

Answer (score 825, accepted):

Sounds like you almost knew what you wanted to do already, you basically defined it as a regex.

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $string);
```

Comment: zuk1: regexbuddy is a great help with that

Comment: Here's an example if you want to include the hyphen as an allowed character. I needed this because I needed to strip out disallowed characters from a Moodle username, based on email addresses:

preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_.@\-]/", '', $string);

Comment: Would this work exactly the same with apostrophes (single-quotes) around the regular expression, instead of quotation marks (double-quotes)? E.g: `preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', '', $string);`

Comment: We want explanation about this :) . People come here to see Why it is the way it is. Please consider Regex explanation too! Thanks

Comment: What if we want to keep accentued characters?

Comment: Does it matter single or double quote?

Comment: as noted by @wonzbak this does not keep accent chars

Comment: @wonzbak you want to keep accentued char, use `[^A-ZÀ-Ýa-zà-ý0-9 ]`, check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/a17e50899cb5).

Answer (score 192):

For unicode characters, it is :

```
preg_replace("/[^[:alnum:][:space:]]/u", '', $string);
```

Comment: hi voondo , what's with the /ui  thing.. what do you call it ? can anyone please shed me some light. Thank you.

Comment: For clarification, they're called flags. They're put after the closing delimiter (in this case it's "/", but it could be "~" or "@" or whatever character you want to use as long as the opening and closing delimiters are the same) and change the behavior of the expression.

Comment: Btw, `\w` includes `\d` and so the `\d` is unnecessary.  Also, this is wrong because it will also leave underscores in the resulting string (which is also included in `\w`).

Comment: There's still an error in this, the character classes need to be terminated with ':]' so the correct line would be:

preg_replace("/[^[:alnum:][:space:]]/ui", '', $string);

Comment: Is the `i` flag really necessary here since `[:alnum:]` already covers both cases?

Comment: This solution worked until i migrated to php 7.3, replaced with ```preg_replace("/[^a-z\d\s]/iu", '', $str);```

Comment: this solution works fine with php 8 as well. I think is the best

Answer (score 59):

[Regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regexp) is your answer.

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^a-z\d ]/i', '', $str);
```

- The `i` stands for case insensitive.
- `^` means, does not start with.
- `\d` matches any digit.
- `a-z` matches all characters between `a` and `z`. Because of the `i` parameter you don't have to specify `a-z` and `A-Z`.
- After `\d` there is a space, so spaces are allowed in this regex.

Comment: We want explanation about this :) . People come here to see Why it is the way it is. Please consider Regex explanation too! Not everyone is advanced enough to know what you wrote there without explanation. Thanks

Comment: @PratikCJoshi The i stands for case insensitive. ^ means, does not start with. \d matches any digit. a-z matches all characters between a and z. Because of the i parameter you don't have to specify a-z and A-Z. After \d there is a space, so spaces are allows in this regex.

Comment: People **don't** read comments as answer. Please update answer!

Answer (score 41):

If you need to support other languages, instead of the typical A-Z, you can use the following:

```
preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N} ]+/', '', $string);
```

- `[^\p{L}\p{N} ]` defines a *negated* (It will match a character that is **not** defined) character class of:

  - `\p{L}`: a letter from *any* language.
  - `\p{N}`: a numeric character in *any* script.
  - : a space character.
- `+` *greedily* matches the character class between 1 and *unlimited* times.

This will preserve letters and numbers from other languages and scripts as well as A-Z:

```
preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N} ]+/', '', 'hello-world'); // helloworld
preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N} ]+/', '', 'abc@~#123-+=öäå'); // abc123öäå
preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N} ]+/', '', '你好世界!@£$%^&*()'); // 你好世界
```

---

<sup>**Note:** This is a very old, but still relevant question. I am answering purely to provide supplementary information that may be useful to future visitors.</sup>

Comment: Works for me if I add unicode `u` flag at the end of the regex -- `/[^\p{L}\p{N} ]+/u`

Answer (score 17):

here's a really simple regex for that:

```
\W|_
```

and used as you need it (with a forward `/` slash delimiter).

```
preg_replace("/\W|_/", '', $string);
```

Test it here with this great tool that explains what the regex is doing:

http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: You still need the `/u` flag otherwise non-ascii letters are also removed.

Comment: Neat [but would also match spaces](https://www.regex101.com/r/afwxAB/1) and if this is wanted, probably could double the performance by use of a *character class* and additional *quantifier* for *one or more* [`[\W_]+`](https://www.regex101.com/r/afwxAB/2)

Answer (score 16):

```
[\W_]+
```

```
$string = preg_replace("/[\W_]+/u", '', $string);
```

It select all not A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and delete it.

See example here: https://regexr.com/3h1rj

```
<?php

$strings="

_____________________
--> Welcome to RegExr v2.1 by gskinner.com, proudly hosted by Media Temple!

Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll over matches or the expression for details. Undo mistakes with ctrl-z. Save Favorites & Share expressions with friends or the Community. Explore your results with Tools. A full Reference & Help is available in the Library, or watch the video Tutorial.

Sample text for testing: ª²³µ - Académie Française ______________---__
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
0123456789 _+-.,!@#$%^&*();\\/|<>\"\'
12345 -98.7 3.141 .6180 9,000 +42
555.123.4567    +1-(800)-555-2468
foo@demo.net    bar.ba@test.co.uk
www.demo.com    http://foo.co.uk/
http://regexr.com/foo.html?q=bar
https://mediatemple.net
";

/* No line break */
$string = preg_replace("/[\W]+/u", '', $strings);
echo "Option 1:".$string;
/* Keep line break */
$string = preg_replace("/[^\n\w]+/u", '', $strings);
echo "\n\nOption 2:". $string;
?>
```

Output for php 8.1.12

```
Option 1: _____________________WelcometoRegExrv21bygskinnercomproudlyhostedbyMediaTempleEdittheExpressionTexttoseematchesRollovermatchesortheexpressionfordetailsUndomistakeswithctrlzSaveFavoritesShareexpressionswithfriendsortheCommunityExploreyourresultswithToolsAfullReferenceHelpisavailableintheLibraryorwatchthevideoTutorialSampletextfortestingÂªÂ²Â³ÂµAcadÃ©mieFranÃ§aise________________abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_1234598731416180900042555123456718005552468foodemonetbarbatestcoukwwwdemocomhttpfoocoukhttpregexrcomfoohtmlqbarhttpsmediatemplenet

Option 2: 

_____________________
WelcometoRegExrv21bygskinnercomproudlyhostedbyMediaTemple

EdittheExpressionTexttoseematchesRollovermatchesortheexpressionfordetailsUndomistakeswithctrlzSaveFavoritesShareexpressionswithfriendsortheCommunityExploreyourresultswithToolsAfullReferenceHelpisavailableintheLibraryorwatchthevideoTutorial

SampletextfortestingÂªÂ²Â³ÂµAcadÃ©mieFranÃ§aise________________
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
0123456789_
1234598731416180900042
555123456718005552468
foodemonetbarbatestcouk
wwwdemocomhttpfoocouk
httpregexrcomfoohtmlqbar
httpsmediatemplenet
```

Comment: what does this regex /[\W_]+/u means ?

Comment: `\W` is the inverse of `\w` which are characters `A-Za-z0-9_`. So `\W` will match any character that is not `A-Za-z0-9_` and remove them. The `[]` is a [character set boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). The`+` is redundant on a character set boundary but normally means 1 or more character. The `u` flag expands the expression to include unicode character support, meaning it will not remove characters beyond character code 255 such as `ª²³µ` . Example of various usages https://3v4l.org/hSVV5 with unicode and ascii characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_replace("/\W+/", '', $string)
```

You can test it here : http://regexr.com/

Comment: Per @Alex Stevens answer, this doesn't catch underscores "_".

Comment: i mean to be fair underscores aren't alphanumeric

Answer (score 0):

If someone want to keep accentued characters, just use

```
preg_replace("/[^A-ZÀ-Ýa-zà-ý0-9 ]/", '', $string)
```

check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/a17e50899cb5).