# Remove all non-alphanumeric characters using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can I remove all non alphanumeric characters from a string in PHP?

This is the code, that I'm currently using:

```
$url = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

It only replaces blank spaces.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove non alphanumeric characters in a string? (including ß, Ê, etc.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271607/how-do-i-remove-non-alphanumeric-characters-in-a-string-including-ss-e-etc)

Comment: @mario: That's a bit different since it deals with Unicode. I'm sure a perfect duplicate exists tho...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove non-alphanumeric characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659025/remove-non-alphanumeric-characters)

Answer (score 135, accepted):

```
$url = preg_replace('/[^\da-z]/i', '', $string);
```

Comment: In case anyone else was momentarily confused by Xeoncross' comment at first glance, his point was that the answer *doesn't* support Unicode characters.  But the solution in Xeoncross' link *does*.

Answer (score 20):

At first take this is how I'd do it

```
$str = 'qwerty!@#$@#$^@#$Hello%#$';

$outcome = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $str);

var_dump($outcome);
//string(11) "qwertyHello"
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 15):

Not sure why no-one else has suggested this, but this seems to be the simplest regex:

```
preg_replace("/\W|_/", "", $string)
```

You can see it in action here, too: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/0sg-314

Comment: The simplest and efficient at the same time is `preg_replace("/[\W_]+/", "", $string)`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use,

```
$url = preg_replace('/[^\da-z]/i', '', $string);
```

You can use for unicode characters,

```
$url = preg_replace("/[^[:alnum:][:space:]]/u", '', $string);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
preg_replace('/[\s\W]+/', '', $string)
```

Seems to work, actually the example was in PHP documentation on preg_replace

Comment: Keep in mind that this will *keep* underscores as they are considered word characters and keeps spaces as well

Comment: I didn't know about underscores, but it isn't keeping spaces.

Answer (score 3):

```
$alpha = '0-9a-z'; // what to KEEP
$regex = sprintf('~[^%s]++~i', preg_quote($alpha, '~')); // case insensitive

$string = preg_replace($regex, '', $string);
```