# Special symbols in PHP errors

Tags: php, html, forms

When a user inserts special symbols `\\` or `//` in search box, I get following error:

`Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity`

How to remove it?

```
    $q=$_GET["abc"];
    $xml = "http://abc/seach?q=".urlencode($q);     
    $Obj = simplexml_load_file($xml);
```

Comment: If you access the URL directly in your browser do you get a well formed XML response?

Comment: The $xml is most likely not being loaded correctly. Check what $xml contains before passing it into simplexml_load_file

Comment: @lamplightdev How to do that... is it simply `if(!obj)`

Comment: @sandbox yes, simplexml_load_file returns FALSE if it fails.

Comment: @lamplightdev Is there any function in PHP which returns only ALPHABETS, NUMBERS and White SPACE from string?

Comment: @sandbox this is not the right place for further questions. A quick search brings up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659025/removing-non-alphanumeric-characters-with-php

Answer (score 0):

Why not just remove those symbols (i.e. filter input, which you should be doing anyway) with something like this:

**[EDIT]**

```
$q = $_GET["abc"];

// Array of character patterns not allowed
$not_allowed = Array('\\','//');

// Strip from query
$q = str_replace($not_allowed,'',$q);

// Pass to XML
....
```

Comment: You do not need the `foreach` loop here. `str_replace` can accept and array of items to replace. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9413187/461813

Answer (score 0):

My best guess, given the information here, is that the script your are accessing is at fault here and not your code. I would suggest that it is not handling the slashes correctly and returning an invalid XML response.

There are three ways around this.

1. Get them to fix their script so it can handle the slashes
2. Remove the slashes from the query before it is sent over:
   `$q = str_replace(array('//', '\\'), '', $q);`
3. Attempt to check the headers or XML response for errors