# PHP Regex allow only a-z A-Z 1-9 and replace spaces with underscore

Tags: php, regex

So i need `preg_replace()` to

- remove all characters but a-z A-Z 1-9
- replace spaces with single underscore `\s+`
- if there's multiple underscores in string it need to be replaced with
  single one `[_]+`

Code

```
$str = "Hz!!    zÒ142______23 4";
$str = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9][_]+\s+/', '_', $str);
echo $str; //Outputs: Hz_z142_23_4
```

**Edit** i'd like to do it with single preg_replace

Comment: what's ur expected output?

Comment: i need `Hz_z142_23_4`

Comment: how about `preg_replace('/[^\w]+|[_]+/','_',$str)`

Comment: @bansi That will also replace `Ò` with `_`, which OP doesn't want.

Comment: @RohitJain you are correct. I missed that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove non-alphanumeric characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659025/how-to-remove-non-alphanumeric-characters)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in two replacements:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^\w\s]+/', '', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '_', $str);
```

Or, as in comments, you can combine them into one:

```
preg_replace(array('/[^\w\s]+/', '/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/'), array('', '_'), $str);
```

Comment: `preg_replace(array('/[^\w\s]+/','/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/'), array('','_'), $str);`  just combine it all to become one

Comment: How would i go about adding say one more symbol to allowd say exclamation mark "!"

Comment: Roman Toasov put it after the \s inside the brackets and 9 inside the brackets.