# how to clean a dirty csv string using php regex

Tags: php

my string may be like this:

`@ *lorem.jpg,,, ip sum.jpg,dolor ..jpg,-/ ?`

in fact - it is a dirty `csv` string - having names of jpg images

I need to remove `any` non-alphanum chars - from `both sides` of the string
then - inside the resulting string - remove the same - `except` commas and dots
then - remove duplicates commas and dots - if any - replace them with single ones

so the final result should be:
`lorem.jpg,ipsum.jpg,dolor.jpg`

I firstly tried to remove any white space - anywhere

```
$str = str_replace(" ", "", $str);
```

then I used various forms of `trim` functions - but it is tedious and a lot of code

the additional problem is - duplicates commas and dots may have `one` or `more` instances - for example - `..` or `,,,,`

is there a way to solve this using regex, pls ?

Comment: Is this helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659025/how-to-remove-non-alphanumeric-characters

Comment: Once you removed the spaces, the regular expression `(\w+\.\w+)` should be enough to extract all the file names using preg_match_all. You can then use implode to join those results with a comma between them.

Comment: @CBroe - interesting, thanks, I will try. But I suppose duplicates commas and dots are still the problem

Comment: Can you try this $result = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9,.]/", '', $str);

Comment: @SelVazi - it works except last comma - but I can remove it by `rtrim`. But it does not remove duplicates commas and dots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### List of modeled steps following your words:

#### Step 1

- *"remove any non-alphanum chars from both sides of the string"*
- ***translated:*** remove trailing and tailing consecutive [^a-zA-Z0-9] characters
- ***regex:*** replace `^[^a-zA-Z0-9]*(.*?)[^a-zA-Z0-9]*$` with `$1`

#### Step 2

- *"inside the resulting string - remove the same - except commas and dots"*
- ***translated:*** remove any [^a-zA-Z0-9.,]
- ***regex:*** replace `[^a-zA-Z0-9.,]` with empty string

#### Step 3

- *"remove duplicates commas and dots - if any - replace them with single ones"*
- ***translated:*** replace consecutive [,.] as a single
  instance
- ***regex:*** replace `(\.{2,})` with `.`
- ***regex:*** replace `(,{2,})` with `,`

### PHP Demo:

https://onlinephp.io/c/512e1

```
<?php

$subject = " @ *lorem.jpg,,, ip sum.jpg,dolor ..jpg,-/ ?";

$firstStep = preg_replace('/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]*(.*?)[^a-zA-Z0-9]*$/', '$1', $subject);
$secondStep = preg_replace('/[^a-z,A-Z0-9.,]/', '', $firstStep);
$thirdStepA = preg_replace('(\.{2,})', '.', $secondStep);
$thirdStepB = preg_replace('(,{2,})', ',', $thirdStepA);

echo $thirdStepB; //lorem.jpg,ipsum.jpg,dolor.jpg
```

Comment: thanks a lot, especially for your explanations

Comment: I like to take care of those details. It also helps me improving. Glad it helped and thanks for pointing out the "decoration" aspect

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this :

```
$string = ' @ *lorem.jpg,,,,  ip sum.jpg,dolor .jpg,-/ ?';
// this will left only alphanumirics
$result = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9,.]/", '', $string);

// this will remove duplicated dot and ,
$result = preg_replace('/,+/', ',', $result);
$result = preg_replace('/\.+/', '.', $result);

// this will remove ,;. and space from the end
$result = preg_replace("/[ ,;.]*$/", '', $result);
```

Comment: tried, works - except duplicates commas and dots

Comment: I made a little update to remove duplicated commas and dots can you try it

Answer (score 1):

Look at

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

It replace anything inside a string based on pattern. \s represent all space char, but care of NBSP (non breakable space, \h match it )

Exemple 4

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $str);
```

It will be something like that